# What neural network structure to use for multiple correlated time series predictions?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, multivariate-analysis

The specific scenario I have is this: I have a bunch of players playing a game in which they sequentially make choices that do not affect each other. I believe that each player has some patterns of choices that they have a tendency to follow, but also that there are patterns that all players follow. I have the data of the decisions that all player made at all time points. I also have auxiliary data on each player that could be helpful in predicting what choices the player is likely to make.

- For concreteness, as an example, suppose that the players are MLB pitchers, and they want to choose a pitching zone to throw the ball out. Each player is going to have his own pattern of throwing, but there are likely other patterns that I could get the machine to learn by looking at the data from the other players that could be used to help in predicting the current.

I'm trying to train a neural network to try to predict a player's future decisions. What is a good ANN architecture to use? I think some sort of RNN would work best, but I don't know what design would work.

Comment: just make sure the nn doesn't believe anomalies and challenges them and adjusts for them ...

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: unusual values (untreated) can lead to poor predictions. NN tries to detect patterns BUT if there are unusual values this can lead to a deficient model as a standard NN believes the data and doesn't challenge it.for consistency .